# Json extracting list of field names for a key

Tags: json, linux, shell, jq

jq is a great tool.   If I have a json file, I can extract the list of keys

like so:

```
jq keys filename | tr -d '][",'
```

eg:

```
$jq  keys pipeline/components/devsvr.json  | tr -d '][",'
server1
server2
```

Now I'd like to iterate over each key, listing the top-level field names only (I'm trying to write a very simple validator for some CloudFormation json files).

The shell part is easy - just a for loop, but I can't work out how to say to jq: "show me all the field-names only for key x.

I'll then (in shell) check that each field I require is present.  As an aside, jq will report with an error if the json is malformed, which is useful as well.

Here's an example file:

```
{
  "server1": {
    "type": "single-instance",
    "stage": "10default",
    "descriptor": {
      "Resources": {
        "Instance": {
          "Properties": {
            "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
            "ImageId": {
              }
            }
          },
          "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
              "app": {
                "packages": {
                  "yum": {
                    "tmux": [],
                    "vim": []
                  }
                },
                "files": {
                "sources": {},
                "commands": {},
                "services": {}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "server2": {
    "type": "single-instance",
    "stage": "10default",
    "descriptor": {
      "Resources": {
        "Instance": {
          "Properties": {
            "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
            "ImageId": {
              }
            }
          },
          "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
              "app": {
                "packages": {
                  "yum": {
                    "tmux": [],
                    "vim": []
                  }
                },
                "files": {
                "sources": {},
                "commands": {},
                "services": {}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So with the example above, I'd run jq keys  to get the list of keys, then iterate over that.  I've possibly answered my own question with the sed example which I've commented with, but that's a bit heath-robinson, IMO.  Here's the result:

```
$jq  '.server1' /tmp/afile   | sed -n 's#^  \"\([^"]*\).*$#\1#p'
type
stage
descriptor
```

(that would be in a loop around the output of  the jq 'keys' command).

Update: As per @peak and @Aaron, I can do this:

```
jq -r '. as $in | keys[] | . as $serverName | $in[$serverName] | keys | join(",") | "\($serverName) : \(.)"' pipeline/components/devsvr.json
devsvr : descriptor,stage,type
devsvr1 :
```

With the proviso that http://json-schema.org exists for a more rigorous implementation.

Comment: Include an excerpt from your input file and an example of desired result in your question please.

Comment: I could probably rely on the output of jq being nicely formatted, and search for lines which start with 2 spaces - eg: jq  '.devsvr' pipeline/components/devsvr.json   | sed -n 's#^  \"\([^"]*\).*$#\1#p'

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel (as a square): https://json-schema.org/

Comment: Added an example file and code as per @oguzismail

Comment: @ke2mgl  Yes, I see your point - except that this is something super-quick and easy.  I don't need to write a schema. (Although this is CloudFormation so someone else must have done this already - I know that there's the Amazon cli command  "aws cloudformation validate-template", but the cli is not installed on the server in question.  This is meant to be a quick "if it's not valid, stop now" test, using as small a toolset as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... using as small a toolset as possible.

As far as processing the JSON is concerned, it seems you need look no further than jq.

For example, your first command can be simplified to:

```
jq -r 'keys[]' devsvr.json
```

Use `keys_unsorted` if you want the keys in the original order.

More importantly, iterating over the keys can (and probably should) be done in jq. I'm not sure what your exact requirements are but you should easily be able to adapt the following:

```
jq -r '.[] | keys_unsorted[]' devsvr.json
```

which produces:

```
type
stage
descriptor
type
stage
descriptor
```

### Update

In accordance with the update to the Q, the following filter should be considered:

```
 keys[] as $serverName 
 | .[$serverName] 
 | "\($serverName) : \(keys|join(","))"
```

Comment: Maybe something like `. as $in | keys[] | . as $serverName | $in[$serverName] | keys | join(",") | "\($serverName) : \(.)"` to retain the association between the server node and it's fields' names.

Comment: Thanks, both - this is exactly what I was trying to do - especially @Aaron's addition.  I do this: jq -r '. as $in | keys[] | . as $serverName | $in[$serverName] | keys | join(",") | "\($serverName) : \(.)"' pipeline/components/devsvr.json
devsvr : descriptor,stage,type
devsvr1 :